# highchart to plot combined line chart per bar instead of per xAxis label

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to plot column + line chart combined using Highcharts.

Similar to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/

but, I wanted to plot the line points per bar instead of per xAxis label. Not sure if this is even doable?

I tried to give it a shot but no success!
https://jsfiddle.net/e5e6bcfL/6/

Here is the xAxis categories and series data:

```
 xAxis: {
        categories: ['John', 'Ginni', 'Vicki', 'Alan', 'Alic']
 }
 ...

 series: [{
        name: 'Male',
        data: [10, 1, 8, 7, null]
    }, {
        name: 'Female',
        data: [null, 12, 9, 2, 7]
    }, 
    {
      yAxis: 1,
      name: 'avgAge',
      type: 'spline',
      // this data is per xAxis category and per name/legend
      // eg John Male avgAge is 35, Ginni Female avgAge is 30
      data: [35, 18, 30, 28, 26, 32, 25, 36]
    }]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify x value for the spline points. The middle of the category are integers 0,1,2, etc. If there are more than 1 column in the category they are moved a little to the left/right. In this case if you want to have the spline points above males you need to subtract 0.2 from the corresponded integer. https://jsfiddle.net/e5e6bcfL/8/

Comment: Thanks morganfree. This is so perfect. Here is the final solution as I wanted: https://jsfiddle.net/e5e6bcfL/9/